# Placeholders within UAA_CONFIG_YAML environment variable

Tags: cloudfoundry-uaa, pivotal-web-services

I'm trying to set the SMTP settings within the UAA_CONFIG_YAML section of the manifest.

```
smtp: 
   host: ${vcap.services.smtpdev.credentials.hostname:localhost} 
   port: 2525 
   user: ${vcap.services.smtpdev.credentials.username:user} 
   password: ${vcap.services.smtpdev.credentials.password:password}
```

This doesn't work yet the default of localhost is being picked up. If I provide an invalid placeholder it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
The way I have done it, I have set the UAA_CONFIG_PATH environment variable which points to the location of the yaml file. 
The settings are provided as follows:
smtp:
  host: smtp.gmail.com
  port: <port_number>
  auth: true
  starttls.enable: false
  user: <username>
  password: <password>

These values are getting picked up by uaa. 
Please let me know if it was helpful.
```

Comment: Yeah but then credentials are present in the source code. It should be able to get the credentials from the service binding in the environment but apparently not.